# Labelling points on world map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a world map with the use of the ggplot2 library.

[image: Map]

I am attempting to label the two cities (Shanghai and Sao Paulo) respectively through using labels in ggplot2. However, when I try to add labels I get the error message:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: labels
Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y, label
```

Here is the full code:

```
require(maps)
require(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)

countries = c("Sao Paulo","Shanghai")

global <- map_data("world")
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = global, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = 
group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = global, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), 
fill = NA, color = "red") + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)

gg1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = global, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), 
fill = "green", color = "blue") + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)
gg1

labs <- data.frame(
  long = c(-46.625290,121.4580600),
  lat = c(-23.533773,31.2222200),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)  

gg1 + 
  geom_point(data = labs, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red", size 
= 5) + ggtitle("World Map") + geom_text(aes(labels=countries),vjust=0, 
colour="red")
```

Clearly, I'm using ggplot wrong in some way but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

```
labs$countries <- countries
gg1 + 
    geom_point(data=labs, aes(long, lat), colour="red", size=5) + 
    ggtitle("World Map") +
    geom_text(data=labs, aes(long, lat, label=countries))
```

[image]